# Log file not created inside Task.Factory.StartNew()

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

For the following sample code, I don't see the Log file "ParallelLog.txt" created in C: drive. (Apologies for the big chunk of code!)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace Logger
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee{Name = "William", Age=30, RollNo=1234},
            new Employee{Name = "Martin", Age=29, RollNo=1235},
            new Employee{Name = "Richard", Age=28, RollNo=1236},
            new Employee{Name = "Baldwin", Age=27, RollNo=1237}
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (Employee employee in employees.AsParallel().AsOrdered())
                {
                    WriteToLog(employee);
                }
            });
        }

        public static void WriteToLog(Employee employee)
        {            
            static string fileName = @"C:\ParallelLog.txt";
            private static object lockObject = new object();

            lock (lockObject)
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, true);
                writer.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", employee.Name, employee.Age, employee.RollNo);
                writer.Close();
                writer.Dispose();
                writer = null;
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Employee
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int RollNo { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

Is there something wrong in my code above? This sample is the base for my actual project's log file creation process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace Logger
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee{Name = "William", Age=30, RollNo=1234},
            new Employee{Name = "Martin", Age=29, RollNo=1235},
            new Employee{Name = "Richard", Age=28, RollNo=1236},
            new Employee{Name = "Baldwin", Age=27, RollNo=1237}
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                WriteToLog();
            });
        }

        public static void WriteToLog()
        {            
            static string fileName = @"C:\ParallelLog.txt";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
            {
                foreach (Employee employee in employees.AsParallel().AsOrdered())
                    writer.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", employee.Name, employee.Age, employee.RollNo);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Employee
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int RollNo { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

In this case there is no need for the use of a `lock`. This is removing the successive instantiation of a `StreamWriter` object to just one. Here you do not have to worry about management as this is handled by the `using` keyword. Please see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) for recommended way to use the `StreamWriter` class.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. It worked.. Many thanks!! But still I don't understand why my implementation doesn't work?

Comment: You are opening and closing that file successively and very quickly, this is merely not the way to do it. If you wanted to lock any thing I would make the StreamWriter global and lock that - but this still is not good. if you are not getting an error I am not sure why it is no working as expected.

Comment: The same code I tried in this way, it partially work :(           `code`for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { EmployeeLogging employeeLogging = new EmployeeLogging(); employeeLogging.WriteToLog(); }); }

Comment: Nooooooo! This is creating 100 threads on the Thread pool! do it the way I suggested and enjoy! :]